# Bootstrap on phone : carousel stops cycling when user interact with it

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

A bootstrap carousel in a React.js app work fine on PC browser however when using the app on phone the carousel stop cycling when the user press next or previous slide.

How to make carousel on mobile keep cycling after user press one of the next or previous button ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `pauseOnHover={false}` to `<Carousel>` solve the problem.